# Factoring over $\mathbb{Z[x]}$, $\mathbb{Q[x]}$, $\mathbb{R[x]}$, $\mathbb{Z_3[x]}$, $\mathbb{Z_7[x]}$

Tags: factoring

I want to factor $2x^5$ + $2x^3$ – $4x^2$ – $4$ in $\mathbb{Z[x]}$, $\mathbb{Q[x]}$, $\mathbb{R[x]}$, $\mathbb{Z_3[x]}$, $\mathbb{Z_7[x]}$.
I did it for $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$, but I am not sure it is OK.
$\mathbb{Z[x]}$ = $2(x^2 + 1)(x^3 - 2)$
$\mathbb{Q[x]}$ = $2(x^2 + 1)(x^3 - 2)$. It is the same, since all of the polynomials there are irreducible.
$\mathbb{R[x]}$ =$-√2* √2  (x^2+1)(∛2-x)(x^2+∛2 x+2^{2/3})$.
Now, I am not sure, what to do with $\mathbb{Z_3[x]}$, $\mathbb{Z_7[x]}$ and if what I did is right.
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Factoring out the constants in $\Bbb R[x]$ and $\Bbb Q[x]$ is not exactly relevant, but as long as you don't claim them to be irreducible polynomials (which you should in $\Bbb Z[x]$) it is possible that it isn't considered a mistake.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Oh, all right, thank you. So i can let the number 2 be just number 2 even in R[x], right?

Comment: Yes; you could even say that $2x^2+2$ is one of the irreducible factors, if you don't have a precise indication that they should all be monic.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Okay, thanks. I will just let constants be constants. Now, I need to solve the other things. Thanks.

Comment: You can do the same thing you did for $\Bbb R[x]$, except that you do it in $\Bbb F_3[x]$ and $\Bbb F_7[x]$.